# tried every possible way setting up cron job

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, email, sales-order, cron

I just upgraded from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.2.4 and order conformation mails are not sending automatically. However, If I force send them through admin panel then they do work properly. I have tried every possible way setting up my cron job but it doesn't work at all. after visiting the url www.mysite.com/cron.php i am getting 404 page not found.

Any solution?

[image]

Comment: if possible check by installing this extension : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html

Comment: @BabyinMagento Tried that also but doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure your cron.php at Magento's root folder is present.
Then have your server call it every 10-is minutes inside its crontab :

`*/10 * * * * root php /path/to/your/install/cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

Once it has been called, table `cron_schedule` should start filling up.

Comment: Hi Julien, tried your way too but no luck

Comment: Is your `cron_schedule` table filling up in the DB?